# Fuel system hose routing - Triumph Bonneville

Tags: motorcycle, fuel-system, hose, triumph, bonneville

Can anybody help?

I'm putting 2005 Triumph T100 Bonneville back together. I seem to have got confused with the hoses from the carbs and petrol tank and the tip over hose.

Anybody know of a drawing I can find to show the connections?